# For Loop with Filename Pairing

Tags: for-loop, awk

I am trying to create a script that will, within a for loop, identify **pairs of files** in a directory and then perform a function on each pair.  The paired files are named such as FILENAME_1.fastq and FILENAME_2.fastq and there are multiple pairs within the directory.  Here are some actual filenames in case it matters for regex functions:

```
WT1_0min-SRR9929263_1.fastq
WT1_0min-SRR9929263_2.fastq
WT1_20min-SRR9929265_1.fastq
WT1_20min-SRR9929265_2.fastq
WT3_20min-SRR12062597_1.fastq
WT3_20min-SRR12062597_2.fastq
```

Is it possible to do this without feeding any information about the filename, other than that it has a pair?  I am absolutely awful with regex and name-search functions, but below is my latest failed attempt.

```
cd ~/Directory

for file in *.fastq
do
  sample=`basename ${file}` #I think needs a modification to subtract the _1 or _2 and then a search function to find the paired files
  myfunction \
         -1 ${sample}_1.fastq \
         -2 ${sample}_2.fastq \
done
```

Thanks for any help.  Been stuck for 2 days x_x

***UPDATE***
Please see this [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310374/) for answers on how to adapt the xarg answer for use with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` and `xargs`, and replace `echo` with the command of your choice:

```
find . -name '*_1.fastq' -exec basename {} '_1.fastq' \; | xargs -n1 -I{} echo {}_1.fastq {}_2.fastq
```

Comment: I typically input the file names into a for loop that appends the name of output files and also pipes the output to another command.  Is there a way to provide the pairs sequentially to the for loop?  Note: There are two input files but the output file is merged (so no _1 and_2 designations).  I edited my main post to include an example of the for loop that I use successfully when I only have 1 input file instead of 2.

Comment: I decided to post this update as a new question, as it really is a standalone issue and deserves an independent answer.  I linked the new post as an update in my post above.

Answer (score 2):

to account for the scenario not every file is fully paired , try

```
file . -depth 1 type f -not -name ".*" | \
 \
  gawk 'BEGIN { FS="_"; } { $ 0 = gensub(/^.+\/([^\/]+)$/ , "\\1", "1"); } 
              { inL[$1$2][substr($3,1,1)] = $0 ; }   
          END { OFS = ORS = "\0"; 
                    for (pfx in inL) { 
                        if (1 in inL[pfx]) && (2 in inL[pfx]) && \
                           (length(inL[pfx])==2)
              { print inL[pfx][1], inL[pfx][2]; } } }' | \
  \ 
  parallel -0 -N 2 -j 1 myfunction -1 '{}' -2 '{}' ;
```

gnu parallel allows for functions to be exported. this version of the code will use gawk to handle both basename and print0 functions. This also ensures ONLY files with exact 1+2 parings will be shown in the end, in case there are ones with only one of the 2, or some files with even a "_3.fastq", shall your need to expand into such a realm.

Comment: Thank you!  I am going to try to incorporate this with an if/then argument.  There are cases where pairs don't exist, and those files need to be fed into a different for loop.  At the moment, I put the paired and no-pair files in separate directories and have two independent scripts for each.

Comment: =) also, are your file names ASCII and/or SMB-safe ones already ? i see that you're doing bio-sequencing data. If your work is spanning above the realm of maybe 200MB per job run, consider rewriting the above in mawk over gawk (disclaimer : zero relation to author - i simply like it for its insane speed). It means have to fudge multi-dimensional arrays, and having to circumvent gensub. 

I've re-written my own utility funcs mixing mawk 1.3, mawk2-beta, &gnu-parallel to a point it beats the built-in wc on counting lines, beats tr and gnu sed on simple regex, and beats python3 on url encoding.

Comment: Extra complication:  I am running macOS and the parallel command is not recognized.  I am not sure if it is worth installed gnu, or if there is an equivalent command to parallel already available to me?

Comment: @JVGen : i'm on `macOS` too. with some tweaking i think you can get it to work with `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

In bioinformatics we use this all the time when having a paired end run:

```
parallel --plus echo {} {/_1.fastq/_2.fastq} ::: *_1.fastq
```

or:

```
parallel echo {} {=s/_1.fastq/_2.fastq/=} ::: *_1.fastq
```